# Does the GPS hardware draw power when no app is using it?

Tags: battery-life, gps

That is to say, does the hardware itself do any periodic updating/searching for satellites, etc, if there an no running apps which require GPS information?

If so, what sort of effect does it have on battery life?

Comment: That really depends on the phone and firmware.  I have no doubt that there are devices that power down the GPS chip and those that keep it active.

Answer (score 0):

Most phones tend to cache your location periodically and use this information when requested by you applications so that battery drain isn't a big problem.

I believe this is called assisted GPS.

This does have the disadvantage of allowing to your location to quickly become inaccurate. Imagine if your location is cached as you get onto a train,  you then you take a photo at the next platform, but your location wasn't updated, the location stored in the image could be miles out.